# Navigation element jumps up and down on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, nav

Trying to use .animate to have a sliding  element with absolute positioning. For some reason, the element starts jumping up and down on hover. The default height of the `UL` is `56px`, I want it to expand to `469px` on hover:

```
$(function() {

$('nav ul').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'469px'},'slow');
    });
$('nav ul').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'56px'},'slow');
    }); 

});
```

and the HTML is:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu Icon</li><!--visible menu icon-->
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav><!--end nav-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct code would be:

```
$('nav ul').hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({height:'469px'},'slow');
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({height:'56px'},'slow');
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

this is because you've combined hover and mouseout events.  You only need hover.

hover has two function calls that comprise it: Mousevoer and mouseout.  You call them sequentially, so the code you have on mousever just goes on the hover event.

```
$(function() {
$('nav ul').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).animate({height:'469x'},'slow');
    },
    function(){
         $(this).animate({height:'56px'},'slow');
    }    
);
```

});

However, you need to make sure that you set an appropriate width for the ul, or the hover won't work correctly.  Is there a default width set?